# plot python figure with ticks only and not axes lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I want to plot a figure in python and have only ticks, I do not want to see the axes lines, only the ticks.

How can I do it?

matplotlib.**version** = 1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
fig, ax =  subplots()
ax.set_frame_on(False)
```

to get an intro to ticks, spines etc.  check this entry in the gallery:http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_bounds.html

There's a lot of functionality to change the position and appearance of these elements.  For a lot more on making nice plots check
http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/post/58941062205/prettyplotlib-painlessly-create-beautiful-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

you could try to set the color of the axis to your backgroundcolor.
Assuming white:

```
for child in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(child, matplotlib.spines.Spine):
        child.set_color('#FFFFFF')
```